# Never entering multithread method in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to execute the `do_shit_parallel` function with multithreading.

```
def do_shit_parallel(par1,par2,par3,par4,par5):
    print("function entered")

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for LinkedConnector in FuncGroupTask.Connectors:
        executor.map(do_shit_parallel, [par1, par2, par3, par4, par5])
```

But it is never entering the `do_shit_parallel` method and never printing something

Comment: Ok, with the updated question:  `map` will call `do_shit_parallel` once for every item in the iterable it's given, so it's trying to call `do_shit_parallel(par1)` and then `do_shit_parallel(par2)`... this is also explained in the docs :)

Comment: but it needs to call `do_shit_parallel(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5")` for every `LinkedConnector` in `FuncGroupTask.Connectors`.

Comment: `do_shit_parallel` needs 5 parameters

Comment: Then the second argument to `map` needs to be an iterable, but each time you iterate over it it should return the full argument set. Think a list of lists, for example